# powershell group object and create csv with new header header

Tags: powershell

In Windows Powershell, how can I change the csv output format  of executing this command:

```
$logs  = 'System' 
$today = (Get-Date).Date 
$logs | foreach{   
    get-eventlog -log $_ -After ([datetime]::today) | 
    group eventid,EntryType -noel | 
    sort count -desc | 
    export-csv "eventLog_$_.csv" -notype
}
```

My output must be :

```
"Values","Count","Group","ID","Severity"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","1085","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","1501", "Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","15","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","37", "Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","13","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","1500", "Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","8","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","20001", "Information"
```

But when running the command above, I got this output instead:

```
"Values","Count","Group","Name"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","1085","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","1501,Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","15","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","37,Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","13","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","1500,Information"
"System.Collections.ArrayList","8","System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]","20001,Information"
```

Is there a better way than replacing with csv file modification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure why you would want a bunch of lines in your file like `"System.Collections.ArrayList"` and so forth. You output that you should expect from your command is

```
Count Name                     
----- ----                     
  116 7036, Information        
    5 7040, Information        
    1 206, Information         
    1 14204, Information       
    1 7001, Information        
    1 201, Information
```

The extra information can be stripped out with a simple `Select-Object`. The for each loop is not required unless you acutually have something more in `$logs`. If the case then you should have `-Append` on your `Export-Csv`. You also dont use `$today`

```
$logs  = 'System'
get-eventlog -log $logs -After ([datetime]::today) | 
    Group-Object EventID,EntryType -NoElement | 
    Sort-Object Count -Descending | 
    Select-Object count,name | 
    Export-Csv C:\temp\test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

**A bonus to help**

The above answer might be sufficient but this adds a little to it. I mentioned that your loop seemed odd. If you are looking at other logs than System then i could see a point. I have an example below. Also the return for `Name` contains both and `eventID` and `EventType` and we could do something about that. I create a PSCustomObject that splits the `Name` into its two parts.

```
$logs  = 'System','Application'
$logs | ForEach-Object{
get-eventlog -log $_ -After ([datetime]::today) |
    Group-Object EventID,EntryType -NoElement | 
    Sort-Object Count -Descending | 
    Select-Object count,name | ForEach-Object{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'EventID' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[0]
            'EventType' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[1]
            'Count' = $_.Count
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

The CSV output looks a little better now. The following is from the *truncated* csv

```
"EventID","EventType","Count"
"7036","Information","118"
"7040","Information","5"
"102","Information","1"
"902","0","1"
"300","Information","1"
"10","Error","1"
"302","Information","1"
```

If you only have powershell 2.0 you wont have access to `[PSCustomObject]` in which cause you could do the following instead. Notice the array `$csv` that is built in the `ForEach` loop and is then piped into `Export-Csv`

```
$csv = @()
$logs  = 'System','Application'
$logs | ForEach-Object{
get-eventlog -log $_ -After ([datetime]::today) |
    Group-Object EventID,EntryType -NoElement | 
    Sort-Object Count -Descending | 
    Select-Object count,name | ForEach-Object{
        $properties = @{
            'EventID' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[0];
            'EventType' = ($_.Name -split ", ")[1];
            'Count' = $_.Count;
            }
        $psobject = new-object psobject -Property $properties
        $csv += $psobject
    }
} 
$csv | Export-Csv C:\temp\test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I cant use PSCustomObject . I have to use powershell version 2.0. could you tell me how can I do that with psobject

Comment: I have updated my answer with a bonus that would work in 3.0 or above. Also I added code that would work on 2.0